# oauth2.0 in external browser

Tags: android, oauth-2.0

I've recently came across twitter4j which uses external browser to authenticate user with twitter. I'd like to achieve constistency - is it possible for oauth2(facebook) to apply  similar approach: an external web browser instead of webview and how ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Android Facebook SDK doesn't provide this ability. You have only two options

- use facebook app to authenticate your users
- use facebook dialog with `WebView` inside

But sources of facebook sdk are available and you can rewrite them and create anything what you need

Also you can try to discover Facebook SDK forks on GitHub, it is likely that project with similary options what you need already exists

Comment: thanks, I've also learned out that it's not the best idea from here http://schwiz.net/blog/2011/using-scribe-with-android/